# Why does my font-size not change relative to the screen size?

Tags: html, css

I am using `font-size: 4em;` which I understood to be a relative size? But when I change the size of my window, my font size does not change. It stays the same and starts to overlap and look ugly. The text I am referring to is "Test Title"

Here is what it looks like full screen(2560x1440),I am happy with it
[image]

But this is what it looks like half screen
[image]

And it looks even worse on mobile.

```css
h1, h2, h3, p {
 color: #39382e;
}

.left h1 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ededed, 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 }
 
 .left h2 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-weight: lighter;
 }

div.left {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
 } 
 #upperleft, #lowerleft {
  min-height: 360px;
  max-height: 361px;
  max-width: 551px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="left">
   <div id="upperleft">
    <h1>Web Design</h1>
    <h2>Put your business online for the world to see</h2>
    <a href="#" class="learnmore">
     <div>Learn More</div>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div id="lowerleft">
    <h1>Contact us</h1>
    <h2>Get a quote or ask us a question today</h2>
    <a href="#" class="learnmore">
     <div>Learn More</div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I change the size of my window, my font size does not change.

It is true that em units are relative, however, they are not relative to the viewport, but rather - relative to the calculated font size of the parent element (when set on the font-size property) - which of course doesn't change when resizing the viewport

So if you want the font size to change with the viewport, you have two options:

1) Use media queries to alter the base font-size depending on the viewport width/height (in which case you would probably use rem units on the elements which you want their font size to change respectively) or

2) Use viewport units eg: `font-size: 2vw;`

Comment: `vw` is exactly what I was looking for, appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t set a base size for your font size (in `body` or in `html`). If you set your `font-size` to a relative size in percentile, it should resize properly. Remember that even though `em` is a relative size, it still needs to know what it’s relative *to*.

Comment: I will try, but I assumed that if no base font-size was set, it would revert to the default of 16px?